# how to edit multiple lines using script

Tags: bash

I have a config file that looking like this

```
"gpu_thread_num" : 6,

"gpu_threads_conf" : [ 
    { "index" : 0, "intensity" : 1000, "worksize" : 8, "affine_to_cpu" : false },
    { "index" : 1, "intensity" : 1000, "worksize" : 8, "affine_to_cpu" : false },
    { "index" : 2, "intensity" : 1000, "worksize" : 8, "affine_to_cpu" : false },
    { "index" : 3, "intensity" : 1000, "worksize" : 8, "affine_to_cpu" : false },
    { "index" : 4, "intensity" : 1000, "worksize" : 8, "affine_to_cpu" : false },
    { "index" : 5, "intensity" : 1000, "worksize" : 8, "affine_to_cpu" : false },
],
```

The number of lines in "gpu_threads_conf" always must be equal to "gpu_thread_num" and this num changing from time to time depend on number of GPU's connected.
I have a start.sh script that checks this number and change "gpu_thread_num" with sed, but i can't figure out how to change "gpu_threads_conf".

I lost my hope trying to figure out how to do it myself and really need your help.

Comment: Instead of modifying the file, why not recreate it each time?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's too large and contains more complex stuff.

Comment: If the file is JSON, consider using `jq` to process it.

Comment: @Barmar, unfortunately, it's only looking like json, but it is not.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the comma after the last element of the array. That's allowed by Javascript, but not JSON.

Comment: Seems like this should be much easier to do in `awk` than `sed`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Barmar i'm not familiar with awk, but i'll try.

Comment: You really should get to know it if you plan on doing any complex text processing in `bash`. Doing anything fancy with `sed` is difficult.

Comment: I think @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is on the right track. You can always find the line number that contains `"gpu_thread_num"`. You know the additional lines you need to replace are always `gpu_thread_num + 3`. So why not save the lines `0 - lineno for gpu_thread_num` in a `top_temp` file and lines `lineno for gpu_thread_num + gpu_thread_num + 3 - end` as `bottom_temp`, then recreate this section and `cat top_temp this_sect bottom_temp` into the final config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the number of "gpu_thread_num" according to the number of lines, you can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Take the first line
idx=$(grep -n gpu_threads_conf "$1")
#line after gpu_thread...
START=$(($(echo "$idx" | sed "s|:.*||")))

idx2=$(grep -n "]," "$1") 
END=$(($(echo "$idx2" | sed "s|:.*||") - 1))

#Returns 3
echo $START

#returns 9
echo $END

#returns 6
RESULT=$(($END - $START)) 

#substitute the  number in the file
sed -i "s|\"gpu_thread_num\" :.*|\"gpu_thread_num\" : $RESULT,|" $1
```

it will update directly your config file...

```
sh Test.sh MyConf.cfg
```

I hope with one or other solution, you'll find your happiness :)

Comment: This is a perfect solution and it so beautiful that i can't stop to run it back and forth, lol. That's why i was so slow to accept and upvote it. Thank you very much, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood well, but you can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh


echo "\"gpu_threads_conf\" : [ " > TOTO.txt
END=6
for i in $(seq 2 $END); do
    echo "$i"
    echo     "{ \"index\" : $i, \"intensity\" : 1000, \"worksize\" : 8, \"affine_to_cpu\" : false }," >> TOTO.txt
done
echo "]," >> TOTO.txt
```

Result:

```
$ cat TOTO.txt
"gpu_threads_conf" : [
{ index : 1, intensity : 1000, worksize : 8, affine_to_cpu : false },
{ index : 2, intensity : 1000, worksize : 8, affine_to_cpu : false },
{ index : 3, intensity : 1000, worksize : 8, affine_to_cpu : false },
{ index : 4, intensity : 1000, worksize : 8, affine_to_cpu : false },
{ index : 5, intensity : 1000, worksize : 8, affine_to_cpu : false },
{ index : 6, intensity : 1000, worksize : 8, affine_to_cpu : false },
],
```

Just use END with the number of "gpu_thread_num" and I guess that's it.

I hope I understood well the question.

Regards
Thomas

Comment: For some reason it's not working for me.

    kusayu@laptop:~/oc_nv.sh$ ./foo.sh 
    ./foo.sh: 5: ./foo.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: it works with /bin/bash instead of sh. Now i can just delete "gpu_threads_conf" every time from the config file and put it back using the code from your answer. Thank you very much.